# Can anyone help me with keras Merge layer

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I saw this code from https://github.com/raducrs/Applications-of-Deep-Learning/blob/master/Image%20captioning%20Flickr8k.ipynb and tried it to run in google colab, however when I run the code below it gave me error. It says

> Merge is deprecated

I wonder how I can run this code with keras latest version.

```
LSTM_CELLS_CAPTION = 256
LSTM_CELLS_MERGED = 1000

image_pre = Sequential()
image_pre.add(Dense(100, input_shape=(IMG_FEATURES_SIZE,), activation='relu', name='fc_image'))
image_pre.add(RepeatVector(MAX_SENTENCE,name='repeat_image'))

caption_model = Sequential()
caption_model.add(Embedding(VOCABULARY_SIZE, EMB_SIZE,
                            weights=[embedding_matrix],
                            input_length=MAX_SENTENCE,
                            trainable=False, name="embedding"))
caption_model.add(LSTM(EMB_SIZE, return_sequences=True, name="lstm_caption"))
caption_model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(100, name="td_caption")))

combined = Sequential()
combined.add(Merge([image_pre, caption_model], mode='concat', concat_axis=1,name="merge_models"))
combined.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(256,return_sequences=False, name="lstm_merged"),name="bidirectional_lstm"))
combined.add(Dense(VOCABULARY_SIZE,name="fc_merged"))
combined.add(Activation('softmax',name="softmax_combined"))

predictive = Model([image_pre.input, caption_model.input],combined.output)
```

Comment: You can just install the older version of keras and run it

Comment: The keras model used in that code was 2.1.6. I already installed that in google colab but still it doesn't work.

Comment: did you installed all the pypi packages from this https://github.com/raducrs/Applications-of-Deep-Learning/blob/master/requirements

Comment: Is this an error or just a warning?

Comment: @YashKumarAtri yep I did.

Comment: @desertnaut error Sir. The error is "name 'Merge' is not defined"

Comment: Please include the full error message and backtrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Merge(mode='concat')` is now `Concatenate(axis=1)`.

The following generates a graph correctly on colab.

```
from tensorflow.python import keras
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import Model, Sequential

IMG_FEATURES_SIZE = 10
MAX_SENTENCE = 80
VOCABULARY_SIZE = 1000
EMB_SIZE = 100

embedding_matrix = np.zeros((VOCABULARY_SIZE, EMB_SIZE))

LSTM_CELLS_CAPTION = 256
LSTM_CELLS_MERGED = 1000

image_pre = Sequential()
image_pre.add(Dense(100, input_shape=(IMG_FEATURES_SIZE,), activation='relu', name='fc_image'))
image_pre.add(RepeatVector(MAX_SENTENCE,name='repeat_image'))

caption_model = Sequential()
caption_model.add(Embedding(VOCABULARY_SIZE, EMB_SIZE,
                            weights=[embedding_matrix],
                            input_length=MAX_SENTENCE,
                            trainable=False, name="embedding"))
caption_model.add(LSTM(EMB_SIZE, return_sequences=True, name="lstm_caption"))
caption_model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(100, name="td_caption")))

merge = Concatenate(axis=1,name="merge_models")([image_pre.output, caption_model.output])
lstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(256,return_sequences=False, name="lstm_merged"),name="bidirectional_lstm")(merge)
output = Dense(VOCABULARY_SIZE, name="fc_merged", activation='softmax')(lstm)

predictive = Model([image_pre.input, caption_model.input], output)
predictive.compile('sgd', 'binary_crossentropy')
predictive.summary()
```

Description:

This is a model with 2 inputs per sample: an image and a caption ( a sequence of words ).
The input graphs merge at the concatenation point (name='merge_models')

The image is processed simply by a Dense layer (you may want to add convolutions to the image branch ); the output of this dense layer is then copied MAX_SENTENCE times in preparation for the merge.

The captions are processed by an LSTM and a Dense layer.

The merge results in MAX_SENTENCE time-steps each with features from both branches.

The combined branch then ends up predicting one class out of VOCABULARY_SIZE.

The model.summary() is a good way to understand the graph.

Comment: It worked! Although, I didn't know what happens inside.

Will you explain this for me? Thanks